# $P(X_{(2)}>2)$ given $f_X(x) =\frac{2}{x^3}I_{(1,\infty)}(x)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ are independent random variables having pdf
>
> $$f_X(x) =\frac{2}{x^3}I_{(1,\infty)}(x)$$
>
> Give the value of $P(X_{(2)}>2)$

Would this just be the same as finding the probability that at least two of $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ are greater than $2$? Because if only $1$ were greater than $2$ then that would be $X_{(n)}$, the sample maximum.

If that's true, then I have for an individual $X$ that

$$\begin{align*}
P(X>2)
&= 1-\int_1^2 \frac{2}{x^3}dx\\\\
&= 1-\left({-1\over{x^2}}|_1^2\right)\\\\
&= 1-\left(\frac{-1}{4}-\frac{-1}{1}\right) \\\\
&= \frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}$$

Then

$$\begin{align*}
P(X_{(2)}>2)
&= {3\choose{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{4}^2 \cdot\frac{3}{4}+{3\choose{3}}\cdot\frac{1}{4}^3\\\\
&= \frac{5}{32}=.15625\\\\
\end{align*}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: What does the Notation $X_{(2)} $ mean?

Comment: 2nd smallest of the $X_i$. So $X_{(1)}$ is the sample minimum.

Comment: What does the $I_{(1,\infty)}$ notation mean?

Comment: It means $X$ can take on values from $1$ to $\infty$. It's called an indicator function.

Comment: This is a Pareto distribution. In the notation of the relevant [_Wikipedia_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) article, $x_m = 1$ and $\alpha = 2.$ An alternative approach would be to find the distribution of $X_{(2)};$ you can look in a math stat book under _order statistics_ to see how to get the PDF. // Your approach seems OK. I simulated the problem and your answers match within the margin of simulation error. [Your dist'n can be simulated as $X = 1/\sqrt{U},$ where $U \sim \mathsf{UNIF}(0,1).$]

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct.